# Why would the Russian Annexation of Crimea be illegal?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine, crimea

Hillary Clinton answered a journalist's question about Trump appearing on the Larry King Show, a Russian State TV program. She called the annexation of Crimea was illegal. But, there was a legal process for it ([the 2014 Crimean referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_status_referendum,_2014)). Why would it be illegal since the 2014 referendum showed that the population of Crimea overwhelmingly (96.77% in Autonomous Republic of Crimea and 95.6% in Sevastopol) desired to reunite as a part of Russia?

Comment: Hint: *after* WWII, most of the countries involved agreed to the principle of rejecting the use of force to change border.

Comment: @SJuan76 but 1) the annexation was a result of a referendum, not by the usage of force 2) using force to change border did happen after WWII: the Kosovo War resulted in the independency of Kosovo, and in which US was part of the combat forces of the 1999 NATO bombing of Yugoslavia.

Comment: The referendum was null; apart from the fact that it was conducted under foreign occupation, sovereignty is based in the state so regions generally do not have the right to secede (so the vote was about something that could not be decided in the referendum). And the part about Kosovo is a good one; the general history is indeed way more complicated than the one you acknowledge but in general I agree that Kosovo independence should not have been recognized (the usual explanation was that Kosovo was a case *sui generis* due to etnic violence in ex-Yugoslavia).

Comment: @DylanChensky annexation of Crimea (and supporting the People's Republic of Donetsk) is in violation of Russia's signing the [Budapest memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest_Memorandum_on_Security_Assurances), in which they and America agreed to respect the then territorial sovereignty and borders of Ukraine.  Ukraine gave away her nuclear weapons in good faith that she would be respected, and this has not happened.  Perhaps Ukraine should acquire nuclear weapons now?

Comment: Formally, neither Puerto Rico, nor Guam are annexed. They are still "colonies" (dependent territories). Their citizens are not US citizens and cannot vote (except on primaries).

Comment: @inappropriateCode I think Ukraine (as well as [South Korea, Japan](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/apr/26/donald-trump-stirs-nuclear-weapons-interest-in-sou/), Israel, etc) acquiring  nuclear weapons is risky. What if Ukrainians elect a pro-Russian (or, anti-US) government (again)?

Comment: @Anixx However, these territories were ceded to the US by Spain after the 1898 Spanish-American War. The war was consider an invasion of the Spanish sovereign integrity.

Comment: @DylanChensky I agree, nuclear proliferation is a bad idea.  But the only reason they gave away their nukes was because Russia and the USA said they would respect Ukraine's territorial sovereignty.  It was a rhetorical question - obviously this is a bad idea, but what options do they have to defend themselves?  That's the problem.

Comment: @inappropriateCode according to the memorandum, UK and US should protect Ukraine's sovereign integrity. However, when Russian annexed Crimea, none of these countries sent troops to protect Ukraine's sovereignty over Crimea, and Ukraine should've requested US/UK intervention against Russia. The other way of protecting themselves is joining the EU, however they have to accept various of terms such as passing same-sex marriage legislation and meeting a certain level of GDP, etc.

Comment: @inappropriateCode according to the memorandum, UK, US and Russia should also protect Ukraine's independency. Arguably the alleged Russian support of separatists violates this principle. However, that was also violated when the ousting of Viktor Yanukovich, former President of Ukraine was allegedly planned by the CIA, a US government agency. This was [claimed](http://www.newsweek.com/ousted-yanukovych-plans-return-ukraines-president-432038) by Yanukovich himeself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. Please consider taking this to chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/agora  .  Many of these comments could also be answers.

Comment: Presumably the referendum itself needs to be legal - it's not just automatically legal because it took place. Catalonia also voted for independence in a refendum but Spain remains a unified contry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Legal Usage of Force

Under the UN charter, military force can only be used for self-defense or when deployed be the international community for collective security. 'Collective security' is to be determined by the UN Security Council.

Source: [Article 42 of the United Nations Charter](http://www.un.org/en/sections/un-charter/chapter-vii/)

### The Problems with Crimea

The central problem is that Russia used military force to annex Crimea. The use of force there without the approval of the Security Council (or in self defense) is a violation of international law.

You can find this legal analysis present in many places:

- The [Lexis Nexus blog](https://www.lexisnexis.com/legalnewsroom/international-law/b/international-law-blog/archive/2014/04/14/russia-s-annexation-of-crimea-an-analysis-under-the-principles-of-jus-ad-bellum.aspx) published an article by international lawyer John Balouziyeh.
- *[The Crimea Crisis - An International Law Perspective](http://www.mpil.de/files/pdf4/Marxsen_2014_-_The_crimea_crisis_-_an_international_law_perspective.pdf)*. Published by Christian Marxsen of the Max Planck Institute for Comparative Public Law.
- *[Russia's Annexation of Crimea](http://stockton.usnwc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1377&context=ils)*. Published in International Law Studies, a publication of the U.S. Naval War College.

### Russian Counterarguments

Russia offered at least two answers to this argument.

First, Russian nationals were conceivably under threat in Crimea. Russia does have the sovereign right (and responsibility) to protect its citizens.  However, the legal notion of self-defense for states require an ongoing armed attack (ref: pg.372 of [Marxsen](http://www.mpil.de/files/pdf4/Marxsen_2014_-_The_crimea_crisis_-_an_international_law_perspective.pdf)). Without such an attack, intervention is unjustified.

Second, Russian officials defended their actions on the basis of being invited into Crimea. Both Russian officials and the Ukrainian President Yanukovych have confirmed that this was true. The legal arguments against the intervention by invitation claim mostly center around whether Yanukovych could legitimately claim to represent Ukraine. It seems that although he was not actually impeached by the legislature, he had vacated his role *de facto*.

Comment: The both arguments do not hold water because they justify OCCUPATION rather than ANNEXATION. If the citizens are in danger, their country can occupy the area to protect them, annexation is not needed to protect anybody.

Comment: @Anixx-  If that is backed up by some kind legal analysis, I would love to include it.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: It is also worth adding that the annexation of Crimea is arguably important to the self-defence of the Russian State.  It is not a Western or Centrist view but it is certainly the prevalent view in Russia who have watched NATO move ever closer to their border and towards the only avenue of attack into the Russian state (via European Plain).  If we consider self-defence as a motive, Russia were remarkably restrained.

Comment: @Venture2099 - For international law, preemptive self defense is not recognized.  To be self defense, an army would have to be already attacking Russia.

Comment: “If international law is, in some ways, at the vanishing point of law, the law of war is, perhaps even more conspicuously, at the vanishing point of international law. - Hersch Lauterpacht  The point is, international law is conspicuous in it's complete and utter circumvention.

Comment: @Venture2099 - This question is specifically about legality of the occupation, not any of the practical considerations of that policy. Whether or not it is easy to circumvent the law doesn't matter, it's still illegal.

Comment: You are missing the point of Lauterpacht's quote.  Legality relies on the trifecta of Legislation, Judiciary and Enforcement which means it is not really law at all.. http://www.fed-soc.org/publications/detail/is-international-law-really-law.  I am not disagreeing with your post I am simply taking a broader view that illegal is an ambiguous term when it comes to international law and it is Western publications which state the actions of Russia are illegal.  Non-western sources don't share the same view.

Comment: "It seems that although he was not actually impeached by the legislature, he had vacated his role de facto" - This is simply not true. When the coup took place he was still on the territory of Ukraine and said in his televised address to the nation from Harkiv that he was still the legal President of Ukraine.

Comment: @brilliant In that section I am summarizing the Russian counterarguments. It would be inappropriate to comment on their legitimacy. That is for the international actors to decide.

Comment: In that section you are saying, "**It seems** that although he was not..." - that is your own thinking, i.e. the way something seems to you. That is not one of Russia's counterarguments as Russia never said "it seems". So, you ARE commenting on the legitimacy of Russia's counterarguments, even though you say that it would be inappropriate to do so.

Answer (score 19):

First of all, the referendum was illegal according to Ukrainian law, because in Ukraine a referendum cannot be conducted in only a part of the country.

Second, the referendum was conducted with the support of the Russian Military, which is a violation of the UN Charter and the Russian-Ukrainian treaty about Russian military presence in Crimea (the quotas were exceeded), and of course, the Ukrainian law which disallows foreign soldiers from exerting force on Ukrainian Police and Army.

Since many Russian units participated under a false flag, without any insignia on them and refused to confirm they were from Russia, it constitutes a violation of the Geneva Convention.

But the referendum was not the exact cause of Crimea's declaration of independence. It was just a propaganda and justification tool. What makes the whole annexation thing illegal is the following paper signed by Putin:

[image]

It is the presidential decree on recognition of the sovereignty of the Crimean Republic, and it openly violates the UN Charter.

Everything that followed this was pretty legal: a country can legally accept another sovereign country into itself. It is notable that Putin requested that the Constitutional Court of Russia examine the legality of the law of admitting Crimea into Russia. The court examined the law of admitting Crimea and found it perfectly legal. But, in the text of the Court's resolution, it was pointed out that the court did not examine the legality of the recognition of Crimea. They simply said that admitting Crimea into Russia is legal assuming Crimea was already a sovereign state at the moment. The legality of the presidential decree on recognition was never examined in the Court.

But, of course, one should note that if the recognition of Crimea was illegal, so was the recognition of Kosovo by a lot of other countries, which also was in contradiction with the UN Charter. So, Putin calculated that those countries would not be in a position to criticize him, or otherwise should revoke their recognition of Kosovo.

Since half of the world violates international law, why cannot Russia do the same?

Comment: I downvoted this because it contains quite a few biased or leading statements.  Answers are meant to be expert analyses of questions - not persuasive tools. There are a lot of other great aspects to this answer and I would be happy to upvote if cleaned up a bit.

Comment: (1) "First of all, the referendum was illegal according the Ukrainian law, because in that country a referendum cannot be conducted in a part of a country separately"

– The only problem is… that country was already non-existent at that time. That referendum cannot be conducted separately was written in the Constitution of Ukraine. It was also written in that Constitution that the state power in the country in no way can be changed by means of a revolution.

Comment: (2) By the time the Russians showed up in Crimea the so called “Revolution of Dignity” had taken place in Kiev, in which the state power had been usurped by means of violation of the Constitution of Ukraine. Consequently, Crimea and the East of Ukraine declared their independence because the Constitution did not oblige anyone to submit to those who came to power by means of breaking the Constitution. This simply means a collapse of a country.

Comment: @brilliant even if they refused to oblige the central authorities, this does not give the right to secede. They could invite Yanukovich in Crimea to continue his rule if they wished.

Comment: (1) @Anixx: "this does not give the right to secede" - Firstly, not "secede", but "declare independence". To secede means to separate yourself from existing state that has all legal rights on having you; however, the state of Ukraine that has come into existence after the Revolution of Dignity has never had any rights on Crimea since this new state is NOT the state defined by the Constitution of Ukraine.

Comment: (2) Secondly, says who? Or, better, which law in particular, which they had earlier subscribed to, obliged them not to declare independence in case of a revolution? Yanukovich had been elected President of Ukraine - that state of Ukraine that Crimea used to belong to before the revolution. However, Yanukovich had never been or been elected President of Crimea. Now Crimea was and was actually forced to act freely on their own discretion. There was no law obliging Russia to replace Yeltsin with Gorbachev in case of the collapse of USSR.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but analogy with Kosovo is pretty flawed. There was no genocide or mass repression against Russians in Crimea ongoing by most standards. Whereas Kosovo was put under **UN rule** because of the violence campaign by Milosevic's gov't. One can argue that some of the laws of Ukraine were encroaching on the minority rights of the Russian speakers, but there are many such disputes around the world, which don't get "solved" with a neighboring country invading. Also, no country (and in particular not Albania, despite the ethnicity closeness) has actually annexed Kosovo.

Comment: Kosovo was also discussed a bunch of times on this site, e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74922/18373

Answer (score 13):

Aside from the reasons listed in other answers, the annexation violated at least two treaties Russia agreed to honor:

1. The [Helsinki accords from 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Accords) forbids any non-consensual border changes in Europe
2. The [Budapest Memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest_Memorandum_on_Security_Assurances) guarantees the borders of the Ukraine as of 1994..

Comment: The Budapest Memorandum is not a legal document. Is the Helsinki Accords a legal document? Because the Kosovo War was also a non-consensual border change, Kosovo left Yugoslavia after NATO intervention. There are also multiple attempts including the Spanish proposual of annexing Gibraltar, and the Sinn Fein Party's proposal of advocating a part of UK (Northern Ireland) leaving the UK and join the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: @DylanCzenski An international agreement such as the Budapest Memorandum absolutely is a legal document. And, the fact that a law is sometimes violated is no proof that it is not a law. People can break the law and people can advocate for changes in the law. So can governments run by people.

Comment: @DylanCzenski: The Budapest Memorandum *is* "a treaty Russia agreed to honor". It may not be a legal treaty that the World Court would consider, but that doesn't matter: Russia _promised_ to honor it.

Comment: According to the United States; the Budapest Memorandum is **not** legally binding.  https://web.archive.org/web/20140419030507/http://minsk.usembassy.gov/budapest_memorandum.html

Comment: @Venture2099: "Although the Memorandum is not legally binding, *we take these political commitments seriously*"

Comment: So not legally binding. Taking something seriously is not a legal term or a legal document. There is no such thing as a 'promise' in realpolitik. Let's establish facts before conjecture.

Comment: @Venture2099: Well, the USA is on record for *not* wanting nations to follow international law. Pot, meet Kettle.

Comment: What?  Seriously what?

Answer (score -5):

Actually I think that you already partially answered your question. Do you believe that in a referendum on a controversial issue a result of 96.77% is plausible. Or maybe is simply too good to be true?

Mock voting under guns of Russian special forces actually is not considered as legal way of changing borders (at least outside Russia). The only real referendum was there in 1991 and actually local population voted (with slight margin) on becoming part of independent Ukraine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_independence_referendum,_1991

Comment: Yes I do believe that is plausible. Who in their right mind would want to be a part of Ukraine? Especially given the majority of the Crimean population are Russian. As an example 99.8% voted to remain part of the U.K in the Falkland Islands sovereignty referendum.

Comment: @dan-klasson "the majority of the Crimean population are Russian" just because the Tartars got exterminated by the russians

Comment: @Federico They got deported by Stalin, not exterminated. And it was the same communist dictatorship that later gave Crimea to Ukraine. Before that it was a part of Russia for hundreds of years.

Comment: @dan-klasson Why bother with comparing with so far and much more developed countries like UK? I can find you a much closer example of properly organized voting by Russians. After Hitler and Stalin divided spoils in eastern Europe, in parliamentary elections organized by Russians in 1940 in freshly occupied Baltic states, communist party got over 99% in Lithuania, 97,8% in Latvia and 92.8% in Estonia. And all parliaments voted to join the SU immediately.

Comment: "The results of this inquiry show that 109,956 (46.2%) Crimean Tatars of the 238,500 deportees died between July 1, 1944 and January 1, 1947 due to starvation and disease." sure, they were not exterminated, they only got starved to death. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deportation_of_the_Crimean_Tatars

Comment: @Shadow1024 The reason I brought that up, was because if you believe that 96.77% is implausible, then 99.8% would naturally also be. Because you don't actually think U.K would fake elections like the Soviet communist dictatorship did do you?

Comment: @Federico Yeah right around the time Nazi Germany killed 20 000 million civilians in operation Barbarossa. Whether they were guilty of helping the Nazis is irrelevant. Long before the appalling communist dictatorship, Crimea was a part of Russia.

Comment: The point being, if you disagree with the Soviet dictatorship's treatment of the Tatars. Then surely you ought to disagree with the Soviet dictatorship giving Crimea to Ukraine in the 1960's. Right? You can have the cake and eat it man.

Comment: @dan-klasson  "was a part of Russia for hundreds of years". :D Actually Russians occupied this region for quite short time (from 1783, so roughly counting 2 centuries to SU collapse) For 4 centuries it belonged to Mongols or Turks. (So maybe Russia should cede it to Turkey? ;) ). Before that were Ukrainians (Kiyev Rus) and Greek colony...

Comment: @dan-klasson No, I simply think that Russians faked referendum in 2014, as they for example faked elections in 1940.

Comment: @Shadow1024 Two centuries is a short time? OK fine. Russia should give Crimea to either Greece or Turkey if U.S gives back Texas to Mexico. Yeah,  I didn't think so.

Comment: @Shadow1024 Russia and the Soviet Union is not the same you know that right? It's like blaming Germany for what Hitler did in the 1940's. And nobody in their right mind would do that right?

Comment: "killed 20 000 million civilians" 20 billion people? ok, you're here just to spout falsities. good day to you sir.

Comment: @Federico You know I meant to say 20 million. It's an obvious typo.

Comment: Why you say the only real referendum was there in 1991? The referendu from 1991 was not more legal then the one from 2014 as it violated the constitution of USSR. Even if tallking about 1991 referendum yu should take a look at results in every single region and results in Crimae were against independent Ukraine. Since quite all Ukraine suportes have boicoted 2014 referendum 96.77% make sence.